# Entity listener can inject other Spring dependencies but not repository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitylisteners

I have this entity listener class:

```
@Component
public class AssignmentListener {

    private KafkaService kafkaService;
    private String topic;
    private AssignmentMapper assignmentMapper;
    private AttachmentRepository attachmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public final void setKafkaService(KafkaService kafkaService) {
        this.kafkaService = kafkaService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public final void setTopic(
            @Value("${topic}") String topic
    ) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    @Autowired
    public final void setAssignmentMapper(AssignmentMapper assignmentMapper) {
        this.assignmentMapper = assignmentMapper;
    }

    @Autowired
    public final void setAttachmentRepository(AttachmentRepository attachmentRepository) {
        this.attachmentRepository = attachmentRepository;
    }

    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.BEFORE_COMMIT)
    public void postUpdate(Assignment assignment) {
        var attachments = attachmentRepository.findAllByAssignmentId(assignment.getId());
        var dto = assignmentMapper.mapToKafkaMessage(assignment);
        dto.setAttachments(
                attachments.stream()
                        .map(Attachment::getPath)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        );

        kafkaService.sendMessage(
                topic,
                dto
        );
    }
}
```

and it worked normally until adding this last field which is repository. All other dependencies were injected however no matter what I do this won't get injected. Just to mention this is happening in tests. Do you have any suggestion?